# Is there any synonymous word in English to describe an inoffensive girl?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

In Asian countries, such as China and Korea, populace's aesthetic is quite different from the US.

We prefer a girl who is more sweet, pure, and inoffensive, (my translation is not authentic in English, since sweet can be used to describe any kind of attractive females). And in Asian countries, it is a praise for a girl if she has the characteristics above. I am just wondering whether there are commendatory and exact words in English to describe such girls (not the word to describe their lack of sex experience).

PS:
I once read a paper, named *Automated Inference on Sociopsychological Impressions of Attractive Female Faces*, in arXiv.org. It explores the potential of supervised machine learning in face-induced social computing and cognition. Their research subjects are restricted to young Chinese females that are considered by mainstream Chinese to have attractive faces:

[image]

They run the Baidu (Baidu is an engine same as Google) image search engine with key words: beautiful/pretty/attractive girls/young women, to select the sample images. The Baidu image search engine relies mainly on captions, labels and blogs associated with the images to produce the query results. The selected face images are divided into two subsets, denoted by S+ (sweet, endearing, elegance, tender, caring, cute.)and S− (pretentious, pompous, indifferent, coquettish), corresponding to the approval and disapproval type respectively. And the image I showed belongs to S+. I know the Chinese characters they actually used as key words. However, since the author of this paper is Chinese, I think their translation of their key words searching for images in search engine is not correct. Hence I am wondering whether there are excat words to describe these girls in S+.

Here's [a link](http://cn.arxiv.org/abs/1612.04158) of the paper mentioned above.

Comment: Can you add a sentence where you would use the word? It's not particularly clear to me if you're looking for a noun or an adjective.

Comment: Did you try looking in a thesaurus for the terms you used in your question: "sweet", "pure", and "inoffensive"? Did you try translating the Korean (for example) terms used to describe said women? What results did you get? Where they any good? Unsatisfactory? Why? Your question risks getting ten or more answers, and a mod recently informed me that they are obliged to place a question on hold (i.e no new answers can be posted) if numerous low-quality answers are posted.

Comment: In other words, be as specific as possible, and tell us which words you discarded and why.

Comment: Since the recent edit, I'm uncomfortable with a post supposedly showing what "sweet" "caring" and "cute" Asian girls look like.  Especially as the images are of very young women. The OP has still not said which words they have discarded, and there's still no sample sentence either, which the single-word-request specifically demands.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I had exactly the same concern, which is why I deleted the image as inappropriate. The OP has every right to reinstate it, but in my view that inevitably invites a primarily opinion based response, so I’m flagging it as POB.

Comment: Since this is a translation question, what are the words in your native language that describe this phenomenon exactly for you?

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for words to describe someone's behavior or their outward appearance?

Comment: I don't understand the point of your PS?

Comment: In the West you run the risk of upsetting a lot of people by talking about something like this in this manner, particularly nowadays. Be very cautious.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes; I'm rather annoyed that OP thinks sweet and offensive are antonyms.  I am trying very hard to chalk it up to cultural differences and language barriers, but I am definitely struggling.

Comment: @thumbtackthief I'm sure it's a cultural thing. The East just doesn't have the same social approaches that the West increasingly does. I'm not claiming that either approach is better than the other, but the OP will certainly need to be aware of the difference.

Comment: Thank you for asking. A Stack Exchange question should be objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: The asker has doubts about correct translation of some Chinese words into English. We are told that these words, taken together, describe a cluster of personality traits which describe the "Asian male's" ideal of a praiseworthy woman. Even if for argument's sake we accept the premises, and even if the Chinese words were given, this is impossible to answer. An expert answer would require an expert in "Asian" cultural ideals, the Chinese language, and the English language. This is a community of English experts only, which is why we do not take translation requests, as explained in our [help].

Answer (score 31):

You can say she is **demure**.

> Demure: (of a woman or her behaviour) reserved, modest and shy

[(Oxford Dictionary of English)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demure)

Comment: Interestingly, the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/49879?rskey=Fqp7vu&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) applies the word to 'persons' and does not restrict it to females : _Of persons (and their bearing, speech, etc.): Sober, grave, serious; reserved or composed in demeanour._

Comment: @NigelJ That matches my expectation, describing a man as "demure" wouldn't strike me as that odd. Does it to you?

Comment: No @AzorAhai not all. I was pleased to see that it was so. I think an edit to your question, including this, would be useful.

Comment: Your effort is appreciated. A Stack Exchange answer is lengthy enough to show that it is right. It gives explanation, context, and supporting facts, such as a definition from a good online dictionary. Whatever would make it the right answer, not an idea or opinion. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 6):

***ladylike*** from the [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ladylike):

> graceful, polite, and behaving in a way that is thought to be socially
>   acceptable for a woman:
>
> For year after year women put forward the demand for enfranchisement
>   in gentle, ladylike, mild terms.

Some -- perhaps many -- young women in the US nowadays would be irritated at being called ladylike, because, as the example sentence quoted shows, it implies being mild and therefore unforceful and so probably unsuccessful, and also most likely no fun.  Paradoxically, the same young women might be defensive if called *unladylike* because that word implies being rude and crude and unattractive because of her behavior.

Comment: @ab2 I don't see how it's a paradox at all for women to be bothered by the fact that you're calling them unladylike.  By definition, as they are ladies, their behavior is ladylike regardless of what it is or how you think women should behave.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Please reserve the comment thread for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the question, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Avoid discussion, debate, or giving answers in comments. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 5):

From Latin, the word decorare:  "beauty, elegance, charm and grace.

thus **decorous**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/decorous) adj

> characterized by propriety and dignity and good taste in manners and
>   conduct

As in:

She is a decent and **decorous** woman.

The antonym, **indecorous** is a useful word for a proper verbal quiver!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A Stack Exchange answer should show that it is right. It should give explanation and context. Please [edit] to add whatever would make it the right answer, not an idea or opinion. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 2):

My biggest reserve is with the expression "inoffensive" used by the OP in their title. To physically describe any person, male or female, as being *inoffensive* is slightly insulting.

The person's sex appeal is so bland and dull as to not to possibly cause offense or raise desire in anyone.

Oxford Dictionaries says that *[inoffensive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inoffensive)* is

> **Not objectionable or harmful**

the following is a list of synonyms, listed in the same  entry:

> *harmless, innocuous, unobjectionable, unexceptionable, unoffending, non-aggressive, non-violent, non-combative*

However, the sample sentence Oxford provides might explain why the OP thought *inoffensive* was a term of flattery suitable for a physically attractive young woman

> ‘a shy, inoffensive, and sensitive girl’

None of the adjectives used really describe a girl's *appearance*. They would describe her mannerisms, and *personality*. The authors of the paper, *Automated Inference on Sociopsychological
Impressions of Attractive Female Faces*, cited by the OP, use the following adjectives: ***pure, sweet, endearing, innocent, cute***

I see nothing wrong with these adjectives, they're perfectly fine. These are the type of adjectives that many would use to describe a [fresh-faced](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fresh-faced) young woman, who typifies ***[the girl next door](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+girl+next+door)*** appeal

> *‘…who exudes such familiarity, and who exemplifies a certain stereotype of wholesomeness, approachability, and well-roundedness, while perhaps being a source of latent romantic attraction due to a fondness resulting from such familiarity.*’

In fact, the sense of *freshness* and *health* being representative of beauty is reflected in the following observation, found in the [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ca67/a3d56fe1acb06eb823fbd5138d446f6f2eff.pdf)

> ‘One comment that is frequently made by Chinese male
>   graduate students to justify their approval of some female face images is “look natural”’.